# TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases 'function' object is not iterable

Tags: python-2.7, import, metaclass

I'm working on a project with several packages and sub-packages and got stuck with a import problem:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "***/src/dev/dev_salle.py", line 5, in <module>
    from src.envir.jeu import Salle
  File "***/src/envir/jeu/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from camera import Camera
  File "***/src/envir/jeu/camera.py", line 5, in <module>
    class Camera(object):
TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases
    'function' object is not iterable
```

From what I understand, it have to do with metaclasses of Camera and other classes derivating from object conflicting because of nested import. Some other things I noticed:

- The error stays if I instantiate Camera from camera.py as main

  ```
  if __name__ == "__main__":
      print Camera()
  ```
- The error disappears when I delete the object inheritance, however I want to keep it to use __slots__.
- The error is still there if I create a metaclass MetaCamera(type) for Camera in camera.py
- The error does not occur if I call

  ```
  class Blabla(object):pass
  if __name__ == "__main__":
      print Blabla()
  ```

  in ***/src/, ***/src/envir/ or ***/src/envir/jeu/
- I also import other classes from another subpackage, Pti(object) and Porte(Pti). Pti import is just fine but Porte raise this error:

  ```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "***/src/dev/dev_salle.py", line 5, in <module>
      from src.envir.jeu import Salle
    File "***/src/envir/jeu/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
      from salle import Salle
    File "***/src/envir/jeu/salle.py", line 10, in <module>
      from src.envir.elements.pti import Pti, Porte, Monnaie
    File "***/src/envir/elements/pti.py", line 14, in <module>
      class Porte(Pti):
  TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases
      'function' object is not iterable
  ```

A recap of the structure because it's a bit messy:

```
src
 |--dev
 |   '--dev_salle.py
 '--envir
     |--jeu
     |   |--camera.py
     |   '--salle.py
     '--elements
         '--pti.py
```

I'm used to neither metaclasses nor nested imports so I'm a bit at a lost there...

Comment: While continuing to solve my problem, I move the jeu and elements packages to the same level as dev: the error for Camera disappear but not the one for Porte(Pti).

Answer (score 1):

I finally solve my problem!

And that have nothing to do with nested imports --'

In the two classes whose import raise the error, I defined __slots__ with:

```
def __slots__(self): return ("bla", "bli", "blu")
```

while the correct definition is:

```
__slots__ = ("bla", "bli", "blu")
```

Since the metaclass use __slots__ to initiate the class dictionnary, it raise a metaclass error.